# Empty zip file in Eclipse and Java gives me incremental deprication

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to mod with Eclipse, and when I go to run the code, I get an error.

```
2016-07-09 11:18:31,849 WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2016-07-09 11:18:31,867 WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
[11:18:32] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Extra: []
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleForgeHacks.searchCoremods(GradleForgeHacks.java:110)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:86)
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

And it won't allow me to test my mod. Any help is appreciated. I had also tryed refreshing the dependencies

**UPDATE: Thought I should add this, I'm using Eclipse Java Mars, and Forge 1.8.9, on a Windows 7 64-bit Toshiba Laptop with 6GB of RAM**

Comment: Solved on the minecraft forge fourms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved on the minecraft forge fourms.
Had to delete the gradle cache folder.